# How to do this query in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

The query logic is like that:

```
(A > x OR A < y) AND (B > m OR B < n) AND C = z

db.test.find({$or:[{A:{$gt:x}}, {A:{$lt:y}}], C:z})
```

but how to add B's condition into this query.

Answer (score 1):

Being `(A > x OR A < y)` A and `(B > m OR B < n)` B, then the rest C, wrap them inside an $and comparison: `{$and: [A, B, C]}`, such as:

```
db.test.find({
    $and: [
        {$or: [{A: {$gt: x}}, {A: {$lt: y}}]}, 
        {$or: [{B: {$gt: m}}, {B: {$lt: n}}]}, 
        C: z
    ]
})
```

Comment: But my MongoDB server version is 1.8.2, don't support $and operator

Comment: if $and operator is not supported, do it at application level. This is the way out. You may have to get data in two or three queries and then 'AND' them on app level.

Answer (score 0):

As you can use `$or` but can't use `$and`, you can split the first query group (totally 3 groups) like this:

```
db.test.find({
    $or : [ {
        A : {
            $gt : x
        },
        $or : [ {
            B : {
                $gt : m
            }
        }, {
            B : {
                $lt : n
            }
        } ]
    }, {
        A : {
            $lt : y
        },
        $or : [ {
            B : {
                $gt : m
            }
        }, {
            B : {
                $lt : n
            }
        } ]
    } ],
    C : z
});
```